# new variable lesser of two dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have two columns of dates. The first column occasionally has blanks. I want to create a new variable that returns the maximum date for that row from either column.

```
date1<-c(NaN,"01-11-07","30-11-07","17-12-07","12-12-08")
date2<-c("23-01-08", "01-11-07","29-11-07","19-12-07","12-12-08")
df<-data.frame(date1, date2) df$date1<-as.Date(date1, format =
"%d-%m-%y") df$date2<-as.Date(date2, format = "%d-%m-%y")
df$mindate<-pmin(df, date1, date2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Currently the last line gives me an error:

```
In pmin(df, date1, date2, na.rm = TRUE) :
an argument will be fractionally recycled
```

And the resultant dataframe has no data.

Thanks.

Comment: In Excel I typically use a formula like this: =IF([@[Date1]]="", [@[Date2]], MIN([@[Date1]],[@[Date2]]))

Comment: In each language, the code style is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pmin` doesn't work like `with`

```
pmin(df$date1, df$date2, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] "2008-01-23" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-29" "2007-12-17" "2008-12-12"
```

Or

```
with(df, pmin(date1, date2,  na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] "2008-01-23" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-29" "2007-12-17" "2008-12-12"
```

Or more compactly

```
do.call(pmin, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] "2008-01-23" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-29" "2007-12-17" "2008-12-12"
```